# MySQL table Join for Multiple Values

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables, one with 2 columns of product ids (old and new) that need to mapped to each other and another table with all the product info, including a corresponding product id. I am trying to run a query to double check that the products are matched correctly and it is not working, I need the returned results to show the old id and newid along with the full product info.

Here is what I cobbled together from some other queries I use, but I am not sure I am doing the double join correctly.

```
SELECT `VinylOld2New`.`Old ID`, `asi_VinylOld2New`.`New ID`, old.`title`, new.`title`, old.`number`, new.`number`, old.`image`, new.`image`, old.`added`, new.`added` 
FROM `ii_Product` old, `ii_Product` new 
INNER JOIN `VinylOld2New` ON 
old.`id` = `VinylOld2New`.`Old ID` OR new.`id` = `VinylOld2New`.`New ID`
```

Comment: Please provide some data from the tables and the expected result.

Comment: What's the schema? What fields need to be joined? What do you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Don't mix join notation use `,` notation or `inner join`... not both.  Pick a standard in other words.  Preferably the INNER Join syntax version (the newer)  Also how do New and "OLD" relate?  and what is `asi_VinylOld2New` not a table in your from clause...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pick a standard.  Use `INNER JOIN` or `,` notation both both.  (preferably the newer standard)
2. I'm not sure how you want to join the data here. Your use of `OR` seems to imply you want all records from vinylOld2New and only those that match in ii_product (old or new) but that's a guess.
3. Your 2nd column in select indicates `asi_VinylOld2New`.`New ID` but there is no such table. So is the table in the select wrong or the one in the from?

.

```
SELECT `VinylOld2New`.`Old ID`
     , `VinylOld2New`.`New ID`
     , old.`title`
     , new.`title`
     , old.`number`
     , new.`number`
     , old.`image`
     , new.`image`
     , old.`added`
     , new.`added` 
FROM `VinylOld2New` 
LEFT JOIN `ii_Product` old
  ON old.`id` = `VinylOld2New`.`Old ID`
LEFT JOIN `ii_Product` new 
  ON new.`id` = `VinylOld2New`.`New ID`
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks. Now that I see it I understand where I was off in my understanding.

Comment: you could use full outer joins instead of left joins and see all records even if there isn't a new/old title...  I'm just not sure what you're after.  and note: when using outer joins be careful with  your where clauses.  as using them on a table which doesn't have all the records will negate the outer join making it behave like an inner join.